# how the interaction between one binary variable with several binary variables modeled in logistic?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

I want to assess the interaction among genotype (coded as 0 and 1) and dietary intake {(fat intake ‎‎(coded as 0 and 1), carbohydrate intake (coded as 0 and 1 and also energy intake (coded as 0 and 1)} by ‎logistic regression. How the model should be formed? I should assess them separately in separate ‎logistic model or put all of them in one model? Hope it is clear! ‎

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure from your question what you are looking for.

Possibly modeling genotype (dependent variable) based on the other 3?  If that is the case then you can just put them in one model.  Predicting one based on the other 3.

Comment: I want to calculate interaction of genotype and dietary intake on BMI as dependent variable.So I should place interaction of all in one model or running logistic based on number of interaction?

Comment: All in one is fine.  But wouldn't BMI be a numerical feature and not a factor (or binary)?

Comment: BMI is also binary

Comment: Ok, then logistic will be the way to go!  Running one at a time wouldn't give you much more than you could know by looking at the data. So definitely include all of them, and you can see which ones are the most influential!  Good luck!